# How to use Docker commands inside AspNetCore Website Docker-Container?

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I'm trying to build a docker image inside an aspnetcore docker container. The aspnetcore container is a website which collects data from different sources and then dynamically builds a dockerfile. Afterwards I want to create a docker image from the dockerfile inside this aspnetcore application.

I tried to mount the docker socket in different ways but I cannot use the docker commands inside my container.

I refered to the following link: http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/

so i tried to run the image and mount the docker socket in following ways:

directly in the cmd:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock webinterface
```

inside my docker-compose file:

```
services:
  webinterface:
    image: webinterface
    container_name: webinterface
    build:
      context: ./WebInterface
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  external_links:
    - geonode_geonode_1
  ports:
    - "5000:80"
  volumes:
    - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

and then I tried to use the docker commands inside the container with:

```
docker exec -it webinterface bash
```

but the webinterface does not recognize any docker commands:

```
root@f3e434254601:/app# docker help
bash: docker: command not found
```

I also tried to use the docker remote API to execute commands by installing 
the nuget package "Docker.DotNet" and connect to the docker host as described in the offical documentation:

```
            DockerClient client2 = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine"))
            .CreateClient();

        return await client2.Containers.ListContainersAsync(
            new ContainersListParameters()
            {
                Limit = 10,
            });
```

I'm totally lost... Does anyone have an idea? thank you!

Comment: The solution to this problem is to use the Docker Remote API. A C# solution can be found here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Docker.DotNet. Including this probject inside my project let me run Docker commands inside a Docker container

Answer (score 0):

If you want to execute docker commands you will still need to install `docker.io` in your container (here called "webinterface").

Add this to the Dockerfile of your container-image.